# How easy or difficult is it for a tourist in a hire car to visit Palestine from Israel for the day?

Tags: borders, car-rentals, israel, palestine

I will be arriving in Ashdod in Israel on a cruise ship on or around 1st December and I am now planning the shore tour, where I plan to rent a car and drive in to Jerusalem and cross over in to Palestine, before driving through Palestine and crossing back over in to Israel en-route to Bethlehem and Nazareth, before meeting the cruise ship in Haifa next day.

However I understand Israel's and Palestine's political situation is a little unbalanced just now, so I am looking for advice regards to how best to make the crossings safely and easily.

I have already looked up the government travel advice website and I did not find anything conclusive regards to which checkpoints one should use et cetera, so perhaps would be best getting advice from someone that knows the procedures or has experience in touring Israel and Palestine.

Comment: *"I am looking for advice regards to how best to make the crossings safely and easily"* - can you clarify what you are looking for? The crossings are not like a border-cross. You just keep going on a road... Only going back into Israel there is a checkpoint that shouldn't take more than a minute to cross anyway. Driving a rented Israeli-plated car, you might want to keep away from [A territories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Bank_Areas_in_the_Oslo_II_Accord#Areas_A_and_B)